# Reverse byte array in VB6

Tags: arrays, vb6, reverse

What's an equivalent of the following .NET code in plain old VB6?

```
byte[] reversedContents = fileContents.Reverse().ToArray();
```

Comment: There isn't one. You'll need to code it up by hand. (Standard way is to loop up to 1/2 the array and make the appropriate swap).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a `for` loop

```
For i = 0 To UBound(a) \ 2
  k = a(i) : a(i) = a(UBound(a) - i) : a(UBound(a) - i) = k
Next i
```

Answer (score 2):

If we can assume a dynamic Byte array and a non-DBCS locale, then this is usually fast (as well as a one-liner):

```
Bytes = StrConv(StrReverse(StrConv(Bytes, vbUnicode)), vbFromUnicode)
```

Even when not faster it isn't a lot slower.  However it *is* slower when the array is short.

Time comparison testbed:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Easy()
    Dim Bytes() As Byte
    Dim Iterate As Long

    Bytes = StrConv("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", vbFromUnicode)

    For Iterate = 1 To 100000
        Bytes = StrConv(StrReverse(StrConv(Bytes, vbUnicode)), vbFromUnicode)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Hard()
    Dim Bytes() As Byte
    Dim Iterate As Long
    Dim I As Long
    Dim B As Byte

    Bytes = StrConv("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", vbFromUnicode)

    For Iterate = 1 To 100000
        For I = 0 To UBound(Bytes) \ 2
            B = Bytes(I)
            Bytes(I) = Bytes(UBound(Bytes) - I)
            Bytes(UBound(Bytes) - I) = B
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Main()
    Easy
    Hard
End Sub
```

But in general the "hard" approach is safer.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers were helpful for me, but I came to find out my array is built using a custom Split routine that returns a 1-based array. So the assumption that the array was 0-based didn't work out for me. This routine can reverse 0-based, or 1-based arrays. I realize the original question was for reversing a byte array, but the same logic will apply.

```
Private Sub Reverse(ByRef s() As String, Optional ByVal base As Integer = 0)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sSwap As String

    For i = base To (UBound(s) + base) \ 2
        sSwap = s(i)
        s(i) = s((UBound(s) + base) - i)
        s((UBound(s) + base) - i) = sSwap
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of passing in `base` just use the `LBound` of the array passed in.